# bazel coverage for Java with junit5, coverage.dat file is always empty

Tags: java, code-coverage, bazel, junit5

I'm using the example given by junit5

```
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/main/junit5-jupiter-starter-bazel
```

Due to proxy issues, I'm specifying coverage_output_generator with local_repository in WORKSPACE file

```
# https://mirror.bazel.build/bazel_coverage_output_generator/releases/coverage_output_generator-v2.3.zip
local_repository(
    name = "remote_coverage_tools",
    path = "/home/bazel/coverage_output_generator-v2.3",
)
```

For coverage, I have tried with the below commands

```
 bazel coverage //...
```

```
bazel coverage //...  --combined_report=lcov --test_keep_going --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main
```

```
bazel coverage -s --instrument_test_targets --experimental_cc_coverage --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main
```

```
bazel coverage -s --instrument_test_targets --experimental_cc_coverage --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main --cache_test_results=false
```

The baseline_coverage.dat file has the following content

```
SF:src/main/java/com/example/project/Calculator.java
end_of_record
```

The coverage file at `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/src/test/java/com/example/project/junit5-jupiter-starter-bazel-test/coverage.dat` is always empty

Tried with some other sample applications, everytime the **coverage.dat** file is empty.

.bazelrc file

```
build --define=ABSOLUTE_JAVABASE=<path to local jdk>
build --host_javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:absolute_javabase
build --host_java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_vanilla
build --java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_vanilla
```